# Android: Log Verbose throws error on 2.2 for a new String "byte array" initialization

Tags: java, android, logging, android-logcat

Found this very unusual behavior, when i used the following line for logging

```
Log.v("Upper Case", new String(encryptedActivationKey));
```

where encryptedActivationKey is an `private byte[] encryptedActivationKey;`

This when printed in googleAPI 2.2 logs out for a "null pointer exception", but the same thing runs well on jellybean 4.1.2.

Please help as to why this is happening?

Thanks

Comment: encryptedActivationKey value should not be null

Comment: @newuser how come this works on 4.1.2?

Comment: if the `byte[] encryptedActivationKey` is not initialized then the value should be null. so it gives null pointer Exception. While tring to create an object with null.

Comment: @newuser i have tried it vice versa, both with null and without initialization, still the same behavior.

Comment: The default value of the byte[] is null. so only you got the null pointer exception.

Comment: are you trying to display the value of encryptedActivationKey?

Comment: @newuser Yes am printing it via Log.v

Comment: Try this Log.v("Upper Case", (encryptedActivationKey != null ? new String(encryptedActivationKey) : null));

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36503/discussion-between-droido-and-newuser)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to initialize the byte[] or check whether the byte[] is null or not.

```
Log.v("Upper Case", (encryptedActivationKey != null ? new String(encryptedActivationKey) : null));
```